# find exact rows in dynamodb table java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I need to get the exact count of rows in a dynamodb table. Im new to java so its kind of confusing. My understanding is that you cant use describe table because it only updates every 6 hours.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()));
            Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("<table name>");

        ScanResult result = new ScanResult();
```

//Not sure about this last line. Anyone know the solution?
            System.out.println(result.withCount(1));

Comment: Even though it's possible to Scan table I suggest you need to change the way you think about DynamoDB NoSQL database. It's a great DB if you design you application around it. It's lame when you apply your SQL queries to it and expect same or better results. Scanning table is expensive. Study DynamoDB design guidelines.

Comment: Sorry but vladman is incorrect. I'm a veteran of databases and I'm just as mystified about getting the row count with the plethora of methods that have been introduced over the years in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get the count of items.

Please note that it may **cost** you when you are scanning all the items in the table to get the count. Hope you are not going to run this code on table that has millions of items.

```
public Long getCountOfItems(String tableName) {         
        Long numberOfItems = 0L;
        try {
            ScanResult result = null;    
            do {

                ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
                if (result != null) {
                    scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
                }

                result = dynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest);

                numberOfItems = numberOfItems + result.getItems().size();


            } while (result.getLastEvaluatedKey() != null);

        } catch (Exception db) {    
            throw new RuntimeException("Record count couldn't be calculated ...", db);    
        }           
        System.out.println(numberOfItems);

        return numberOfItems;

    }
```

Comment: I really don't get the point of the `setExclusiveStartKey()` call and would rather not put it in my code when I just want to know the total number of items in the table.

Comment: The point is that the scan will return paginated results. When you retrieve a set of results, if there are more to retrieve then `lastEvaluatedKey` will be set. If it *is* set, you need to provide it in your next query. If you do not set it in your code then you will repeatedly get the same first page of data. (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a `1MB` limit of the scan result, sometimes there are more rows than returned. So just do a normal scan and check your result if it contains a `LastEvaluatedKey`. if that is the case continue to scan but starting at the position of the last record by using `setExclusiveStartKey`.

```
ScanResult scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);

int total = 0;
while(true)
{
    total += scanResult.getScannedCount();            

    Map<String, AttributeValue> pages = scanResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();           
    if (pages == null)
        break;

    scanRequest.setExclusiveStartKey(pages);
    scanResult = client.scan(scanRequest);
}
```